# How to get values of each input field using jquery having same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the values of each of the input field that are under same set. Below is my code:

Input field 1:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="amount[]" >
```

Input field 2:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="amount[]" >
```

and so on....the number of fields are variable.

Now I want to get the values the user typed in each of the field that is named . How to do that in jquery?

I have tried following code but it returns nothing:

```
$("input[name=amount[]]").val();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can get all values in an array

```
var values = $('input[name="amount[]"]').map(function(){
   return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(values);
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/BFjp5/

Comment: Another thing...These input fields are generated by CActiveForm in yii and by default there is no value attribute in the input field. Will it still work?

Comment: @AllSympatheticUpvoters This answer didn't even mention why OP's selector wont work.

Comment: @Hammad That will work even if you don't have value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are multiple element with same name you need indexing:

```
$("input[name='amount[]']")[0].value;
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/WuU7H/)

and for getting all elements values:

```
$("input[name='amount[]']").each(function (i,v) {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/WuU7H/1/)

Comment: Cannot apply indexing as I wrote the number of  fields will be generated by the user. Actually it is about creating the recipe. User can add multiple input fields depending upon number of ingredients they have in the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

by javascript

```
function getValues(){
        var ids=document.getElementsByName('amount[]');
        var ary=new Array();

        for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            ary[i]=ids[i].value;
        }
        return ary;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='amount[]']")
```

This will get you a set of elements. You can get value of each of those elements by iterating over them.

```
$("input[name='amount[]']").each(function(){
    $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the attribute value as a `string` since `[` and `]` are meta-characters,

```
var values = $("input[name='amount[]']")
                  .map(function(){ return $(this).val() })
                    .get().join('');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hy7QS/)

Answer (score -4):

You don't!

The whole point of ID's in the DOM is that they are unique.

Comment: What does this have to do with anything?